# textboxs aren't updating when I select a new option from combo box c#

Tags: c#

My code is this:

```
if (comboBox5.Text == "Primer")
{
    richTextBox5.Text = "This is the number of primer tins" + primer.ToString();
}
if (comboBox3.Text == "Matt")
{
    richTextBox6.Text = "This is how many 2.5 tins of paint are needed: " + val44.ToString();
}
if (comboBox3.Text == "Vinyl")
{
    richTextBox6.Text = "This is how many 2.5 tins of paint are needed" + val55;
    richTextBox3.Text = valcm.ToString();
}
if (comboBox3.Text =="Silk")
{
    richTextBox3.Text = valcostsilk.ToString();
}
```

The code runs fine, however when I go back to select a new option from the combo box it doesn't update the relevant rich text box. As I say, I am new to this all and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a clear function for richtextboxes and call it before string comparison

```
public void ClearAllRichtextboxes()
{
    richTextBox3.Clear();
    richTextBox5.Clear();
    richTextBox6.Clear();
}
```

your ComboBox_SelectionChanged function should be like this

```
public void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ClearAllRichtextboxes();
    if (comboBox5.Text == "Primer")
    {
        richTextBox5.Text = "This is the number of primer tins" + primer.ToString();
    }
    if (comboBox3.Text == "Matt")
    {
        richTextBox6.Text = "This is how many 2.5 tins of paint are needed: " + 
    val44.ToString();
    }
    if (comboBox3.Text == "Vinyl")
    {
        richTextBox6.Text = "This is how many 2.5 tins of paint are needed" + val55;
        richTextBox3.Text = valcm.ToString();
    }
    if (comboBox3.Text =="Silk")
    {
        richTextBox3.Text = valcostsilk.ToString();
    }
}
```